Current consensus on the etymology of Remus
For a long time, Remus was connected to the PIE word for "twin" (cf. Sanskrit यम (yama), Old Norse Ymir, Latin geminus), and I still see this pop up frequently in books on comparative etymology.
Yet I also was pretty convinced by T. P. Wiseman's monograph that Remus wasn't a "reflex" of the Divine Twins, and in fact wasn't invented until the 3rd century (which Plutarch also states). That book, however, came out nearly 30 years ago.
This makes me wonder what advances have taken place since. De Vaan as expected doesn't include an entry for it.
Side-stepping the cultural origins of Remus, though, what's the latest consensus, if there is one, on the etymology of Remus?
